# Match word containing both lower and upper case letters

Tags: r, regex

Matching acronyms containing both lower and upper case letters (atleast one of more lower and capital case like reKHS) or capital case acronyms of length 3 or more (CASE, CAT) in R. Regex should match both reKHS and CASE. This regex takes care of the latter case (matching acronyms of length 3 or more) `regex <- "\\b^[a-zA-Z]*${3,10}\\b";`. Would need to find a way to combine this with the regex containing both lower and upper case.

Comment: why should `CASE` match when it doesn't even satisfy the condition of 1 or more lower case letters?

Comment: `CASE` is part of the second condition. `capital case acronyms of length 3 or more (CASE, CAT) in R.` Sorry that should be an `or`. Just corrected it!

Comment: [`\b(?:[A-Z]{3,10}|[a-z]+[A-Z]+)\b`](http://rubular.com/r/lKC5JUkHhA)

Comment: @sparkh2o I'm not sure how your regex works right now since `${3,10}` is invalid, but @Gurman's regex is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A positive look-ahead or two should solve this

```
(.*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)|([A-Z]{3,})
```

To explain:

```
Either contain a lower and upper case character somewhere 
    (.*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)
or
    |
have at least 3 upper case characters
    ([A-Z]{3,})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a TRE compliant pattern like

```
regex <- "\\b(?:[[:upper:]]{3,10}|(?:[[:lower:]]+[[:upper:]]|[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*[[:upper:]])[[:alpha:]]*)\\b"
```

Or a PCRE regex (use with `perl=TRUE` in base R functions):

```
regex <- "\\b(?:\\p{Lu}{3,10}|(?:\\p{Ll}+\\p{Lu}|\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}*\\p{Lu})\\p{L}*)\\b"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vkr6lA/1) (and the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vkr6lA/3)).

**Details**

- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - either

  - `[[:upper:]]{3,10}` - 3 to 10 uppercase letters
- `|` - or

  - `(?:` - either

    - `[[:lower:]]+[[:upper:]]` - 1 or more lowecase and 1 uppercase
  - `|` - or

    - `[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*[[:upper:]]` - an uppercase, then 0+ lowercase and then an uppercase letter
  - `)` - end of the grouping
  - `[[:alpha:]]*` - 0+ letters
- `)` - end of the alternation group
- `\\b` - a word boundary.